# Can the connection of collector and base in these circuits be considered as a diode connected transistor?

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistors, diodes, bjt

I was learning how to design an op amp and I saw something thatis called "diode connected transistor."

Like this image:

[image]

Later I saw a person that was teaching about these circuits, and he never said the connection between collector and base through that resistors is a diode connected transistor like the above image:

[image]

[image]

Maybe these are not diode connected transistors.

Can the connection of collector and base in these circuits be considered a diode connected transistor?

Comment: Don't think there a transistor with a diode between B and C, unless you add one externally. A connection between C and B usually relates to feedback - an extra voltage at B, will alter the voltage at C, which in turn alters the voltage at B (all at once - not in 3 steps). A feedback situation then requires a solution where all the voltages agree - the voltage at B, produces a voltage at C which results in the same voltage at B that we started from (all at once, i.e. multiple equations with the above constraints - solved together "at the same time").

Answer (score 3):

No, the circuits are not a diode connected transistor, because B and C are not connected together, and your diagram defines a diode connected transistor which has B and C connected together.

Answer (score 2):

The diode connected transistor requires a direct short circuit between collector and base, to be called a "diode connected transistor". That is, a 0Ω resistance, a wire, connects them.

The two circuits you show *do not* have this condition. In your first circuit there's a non-zero resistance between the collector and the positive power supply. In the second, there is a path between collector and emitter, but it also has non-zero resistance. Therefore the transistors in those circuits are *not* "diode connected".

Here's a circuit in which Q1 *is* diode connected, and Q2 is not:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGn8YM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>